# delete lines after a pattern in ruby

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

I have to delete some lines after a pattern from file, in Ruby. For example, I've a file like this:

```
# pattern 1
a
b
# end pattern 1
# pattern 2
a
b
c
d
# end pattern 2
# pattern 3
a
b
c
# end pattern 3
```

I want to delete the lines between `# pattern 2` and `# end pattern 2`.
The file that I want to get is:

```
# pattern 1
a
b
# end pattern 1
# pattern 3
a
b
c
# end pattern 3
```

Comment: i've tried with gsub in ruby, but that can only delete/replace a single line, not a text block. i've searched but i can't find anything suitable for this task.

Comment: Please show the code you wrote. We'd rather show where you went wrong than write a complete solution for you.

Comment: How big is the file you are processing? If it's a reasonable size, that will fit into memory, use `File.read()` to pull it in completely, then a single `gsub()` will let you strip the lines you are targeting, then write the results to a new file. See my comment below about doing in-file changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `String#gsub`, but you need to pass an option to regex, that will make dot match newlines.

```
str = <<-STR
# pattern 1
a
b
# end pattern 1
# pattern 2
a
b
c
d
# end pattern 2
# pattern 3
a
b
c
# end pattern 3
STR

puts str.gsub(/(# pattern 2.*# end pattern 2\n)/m, '')
# >> # pattern 1
# >> a
# >> b
# >> # end pattern 1
# >> # pattern 3
# >> a
# >> b
# >> c
# >> # end pattern 3
```

Comment: thanks it work, but can i write directly to a file? using `file = File.open("/etc/file","rb")` and `content = file.read` i can put the content of the file to a string, but i would like to work directly in the file, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you won't be able to use a regex then.

Comment: @pfrancesco, Working directly in the file is not a recommended practice, for data integrity reasons. If your code fails during the process, your data file will be corrupted, and very likely won't be easily recoverable. You're much better off to read the original, and write to a new version of it, then rename the original to something else, followed by renaming the new to the name of the original. Then you are free to delete the original file.

Comment: i'll follow the suggestions of the Tin Man and the code of Sergio. thanks to everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

I like to avoid regular expressions unless they really are necessary.  In this case they are not.  Just iterate through the string line by line printing each line.  Detect when you see the "# pattern 2" and then stop printing lines.  Detect when you see "# end pattern 2" and start printing lines again.  This can be done easily with a local boolean variable, and you should do that yourself as an exercise because it sounds like you don't know much about Ruby and don't know what to try.

**But** there is a cool trick in Ruby that makes the variable unnecessary:

```
str = <<END
X
# pattern 2
Y
Z
# end pattern 2
Q
END

str.split("\n").each do |line|
  puts line unless (line=="# pattern 2")..(line=="# end pattern 2")
end
```

Comment: it doesn't work because of the `#`, that is a comment. by the way that's not the problem, i'm trying to get it working with the file

Comment: The `#` character has no special meaning inside a string.  I ran the above code in Ruby 1.9.3 and it produced the desired output.  What output does it produce for you and what version of ruby did you try it in?  What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 0):

Love trick of Here document, but if you want to handle the file directly, here is another solution, which plays with pos and rewind (sorry, no exception handling for file io):

```
def gsub_paragraph(options)
  regex_start = /^.*#{options[:pattern_start]}.*$/
  regex_stop = /^.*#{options[:pattern_stop]}.*$/

  f_read = File.new(options[:file_in], 'r')
  true until (line_pattern = regex_start.match(f_read.gets))
  pos_start = f_read.pos - line_pattern[0].length - 1
  f_read.rewind
  part_start = f_read.read(pos_start)

  true until (line_pattern = regex_stop.match(f_read.gets))
  pos_stop = f_read.pos
  part_stop = f_read.read(pos_stop)
  f_read.close

  f_write = File.new((options[:file_out] || options[:file_in]), 'w+')
  replacement = options[:replacement] || ''
  f_write.puts part_start + replacement + part_stop
  f_write.close
end


file = "gsub_in.txt"

# Output to a designated file other than source file, replace matched part
gsub_paragraph(:file_in => file, :pattern_start => 'pattern 2', :pattern_stop => 'end pattern 2', :replacement => "~~~I replaced sth here~~~\n", :file_out => 'gsub_out.txt')

# Output to a designated file other than source file, without replacement
gsub_paragraph(:file_in => file, :pattern_start => 'pattern 2', :pattern_stop => 'end pattern 2', :file_out => 'gsub_out.txt')

# Output to source file directly, without replacement
gsub_paragraph(:file_in => file, :pattern_start => 'pattern 2', :pattern_stop => 'end pattern 2')
```